# Raspberry Pi and Turtlebot

Tags: turtlebot, ros-fuerte, ros-groovy, raspberrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am very sorry if my question has an obvious answer but:

I am new to Raspberry Pi and TurtleBot and ROS. I know I can get ROS on the Raspberry Pi, I found a tutorial for that. But before I go through the steps to get it all set up, can I use a Raspberry Pi as the TurtleBot Netbook? Is there anything extra I will need? Is there an example somewhere?

Also, I'm a fan of Groovy, will TurtleBot even work with ROS Groovy right now because the installation instructions are blank?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

-Kelly

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54761/raspberry-pi-and-turtlebot/) by [kpowell34567](https://answers.ros.org/users/4168/kpowell34567/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-02-08

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DrBot](https://answers.ros.org/users/765/drbot/) on 2013-02-08**:
I was hoping someone already did this! I am working with some folks who think the best approach for ROS on an RPi is to use ARCH -  supposedly it is faster.  I don't know if it will run as a ROS master host.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-02-09**:
I feel sure that TurtleBot will work on Groovy, once all the problems have been solved. :-)

**Comment by [kpowell34567](https://answers.ros.org/users/4168/kpowell34567/) on 2013-02-11**:
DrBot- would you be willing to try to work together on this? I am going to start on the process tomorrow, either way I will post the results here. I am hoping to process the kinect data, or at least send it to the work station.

**Comment by [DrBot](https://answers.ros.org/users/765/drbot/) on 2013-02-25**:
Goal is the RPi will launch the robot and kinnect, but RVIZ will be run on a wifi connected laptop or other mobile device.  I tried to build he openni drivers on Rpi Arch, but the buld failed on the 'clean'.

**Comment by [DrBot](https://answers.ros.org/users/765/drbot/) on 2013-02-25**:
BTW  were able to capture data from both a XV-11 neato node,  and a Kinnect using the turtlebot kinnect launch on an ubuntu laptop using fuerte. This is all work associated with the Ubiquity robotics project.

**Comment by [Srinivas](https://answers.ros.org/users/4161/srinivas/) on 2013-04-17**:
Hi I'm able to launch turtlebot using raspberry pi wheezy with groovy, and teleop using workstation, but kinect is over burden on processor, were  you able to process kinect data?

**Comment by [lui91](https://answers.ros.org/users/20948/lui91/) on 2014-11-26**:
Hi i dont know what im doing wrong, I've installed ros groovy on the raspberry pi and trying to move the kobuki motors with the kobuki node and the keyop but the turtlebot doesn't move. I hope anybody can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you trying to just control the motors, or are you trying to do the Kinect image processing?  I think the Pi is powerful enough for the former but not for the latter.

---

Originally posted by [Jon Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2281/jon-stephan/) with karma: 837 on 2013-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DrBot](https://answers.ros.org/users/765/drbot/) on 2013-03-04**:
The Rpi will capture the data and Rviz will be run on a remote computer.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We are able to run a roscore on Raspian with groovy and use it to control an Arduino.

The build takes forever on a Pi.  Once we get a working build, we burn SD cards.

[youtube](http://youtu.be/6SezZAJZmn4)  More info in google groups ubiquity_robots

---

Originally posted by [DrBot](https://answers.ros.org/users/765/drbot/) with karma: 147 on 2013-03-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) on 2013-03-07**:
check out this link, it also provides a sd image with the mobile and perception preinstalled

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working on getting the kinect to work with my raspberry pi but I have not seen anyone getting a pointcloud from a kinect. So no, right now it is not possible to replace the netbook with a raspberry pi and I doubt that it is possible at all.

---

Originally posted by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) with karma: 1554 on 2013-03-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1